# Mismatched types, expected () found Result when using lookup_host

Tags: rust

I am using [std::net::lookup_host](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/fn.lookup_host.html). When I build, an error occurs. I am using Rust 1.2.

```
use std::net;
fn main() {
    for host in try!(net::lookup_host("rust-lang.org")) {
        println!("found address : {}", try!(host));
    }
}
```

Error

```
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected (),
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate:: result:: Result:: Err (
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
<std macros>:1:1: 6:48 note: in expansion of try!
exam.rs:4:14: 4:53 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
exam.rs:4:2: 6:3 note: expansion site
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected (),
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate:: result:: Result:: Err (
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
<std macros>:1:1: 6:48 note: in expansion of try!
exam.rs:5:34: 5:44 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 2:62 note: in expansion of print!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:58 note: in expansion of println!
exam.rs:5:3: 5:46 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
exam.rs:4:2: 6:3 note: expansion site
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3itr2s/how_method_of_use_to_lookup_host_in_stdnet/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can only use the [`try!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.try!.html) macro from a function that returns a [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html), because the macro tries to `return` from the function if the expression is an `Err`.

```
#![feature(lookup_host)]

use std::io::Error;
use std::net;

fn main0() -> Result<(), Error> {
    for host in try!(net::lookup_host("rust-lang.org")) {
        println!("found address : {}", try!(host));
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    // unwrap() will panic if main0() returns an error.
    main0().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thx, but Is this #![feature(lookup_host)] can in nightly version?

Comment: `lookup_host` is unstable, and therefore it's only available on the nightly version for the moment.